# Google Sheets setValues anomaly?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have function, `gatherAds` which is attached to a button in a variety of worksheets in a Google Sheets workbook. It calls an `ADS` function which runs a library routine that talks to some middleware on our server to pull down Google Ads data. The `result` variable contains a 2D array which is injected into the workbook at row 9, column 2 (after clearing out anything that's already there.)

At the bottom the actual `.setValues()` is in a try/catch. That's because, even though it works, it still insists on throwing an error, namely: `The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 1 but the range has 15.` (or variations on that theme.)

Why does something that works also throw an error? And what's wrong with `worksheet.getRange(9, 2, length, width).setValues(result);` in any case?

```
function gatherAds() {
  const workbook = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const worksheet = workbook.getActiveSheet();
  const B = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    B.push(worksheet.getRange('B' + (i + 1)).getDisplayValue());
  }
  const result = ADS(...B);
  const length = result.length;
  const width = result[0].length;

  const range = worksheet.getRange(9, 2, worksheet.getLastRow(), worksheet.getLastColumn());
  range.clear();
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();

  try {
    worksheet.getRange(9, 2, length, width).setValues(result);
  } catch (E) {
    console.error(E.message);
  }
}

/**
 * ADS Calls GoogleAds 
 * @param  {string} customerId
 * @param  {string} selectClauseFields
 * @param  {string} fromClause
 * @param  {string} whereClause
 * @param  {string} orderByClause
 * @param  {string} limitClause
 * @param  {string} parametersClause
 * @customfunction
 */
function ADS(customerId, selectClauseFields, fromClause, whereClause, orderByClause, limitClause, parametersClause) {
  return DaisyChain.ADS3(customerId, selectClauseFields, fromClause, whereClause, orderByClause, limitClause, parametersClause);
}
```

Comment: Can you confirm that `ADS()` always returns a 2D array whose rows are all the same length?

Comment: Yes, always a 2D

Comment: @bugmagnet - have you tried printing the values of `result` before setting the value? I'm suspecting that the value of `result` is sometimes empty 2D array which causes the error `The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 1 but the range has 15.`

Comment: @bugmagnet But are the rows of the 2D array all the same length?  I suspect that is the issue, as I can reproduce your error by attempting to `setValues` with a ragged array.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible the `result` array is a ragged array, with rows that are not uniform in length.  I can reproduce both aspects of your error (the same error message *and* data gets written to the sheet) with the following snippet:

```
let grid = [
    [1,2,3],
    [4],
    [5,6,7]
  ]
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1,1,3,3).setValues(grid)
```

The first row (`[1,2,3]`) is written to the sheet, and the error is thrown:

`Exception: The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 1 but the range has 3.`

I suspect that, internally, Apps Script is writing one row of the array at a time, so only after it writes the first row does it notice that the following row does not conform to the dimensions of the range.

In your case, you might have some extraneous rows at the end of `result`, so it appears that `result` is being written, but it's really only partially so. You can verify this with

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2))
```

before you call `.setValues()`

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
function gatherAds() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const B = sh.getRange("B1:B7").getDisplayValues().flat();
  const result = ADS(...B]);
  const length = 1;
  const width = result.length;
  const range = sh.getRange(9, 2, sh.getLastRow(), sh.getLastColumn());
  range.clear();
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  try {
    sh.getRange(9, 2, 1,result.length).setValues([result]);
  } catch (E) {
    console.error(E.message);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, though the issue is not with the `B` as a parameter to ADS as much as it is with the `.setValues` which is triggering the exception.

Comment: What is length and width?

Comment: Try it again.  I modified it